# Converting Mesh File To STL

Tags: mesh, stl-format, openfoam

How can I convert a mesh file (.meshdat or .msh) into STL file format?

I have a 3D mesh file. I need to convert it into STL for a CFD problem.

Comment: Is that mesh only a surface mesh? Then you can convert it to a surface mesh. Otherwise you cannot in the first place. STL can only represent a triangulated surface in OpenFOAM. I assume that the original mesh is created using a third party mesh generator?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Yes it is a surface mesh but in 3D. I mean it does not have a thickness but it has Z value which is too small (0.01 m)

Comment: Imagine a bracelet that is made of paper. It has no thickness. But as I said earlier it is still 3D

Comment: You can try to import it into OpenFOAM using `fluentMeshToFoam mesh.msh`, create a zone for the surface (bracelet thingy), then try to export that zone into the STL format using `surfaceMeshExport`. This is just a rough guess.

Comment: Have you tried meshlab or FreeCAD? I think solidworks can also convert surface to part.

Comment: This is two different questions. If you have a mesh and you want to use it in OpenFOAM the best way IMHO is to use Gmsh.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine). It knows a load of mesh formats, STL and msh amongst them.